# Triangular random number generator

Tags: c#, random, distribution

I understand how to generate the random P value from 0 to 1 and also the function which is specified here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution

But when writing the code (C#) i get stuck in the if statements, not sure how to write them because in my situation the minimum, mode and maximum will be something like 3, 8 and 14 while the P value is always 0 to 1. I understand that i'm failing at understand something very basic in the math but i would appreciate some guidance.

Edit: this is the code and of course the if statement needs to be replaced.

```
    public double a, b, c, F, P;
    private Random pRandom = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
    public double Tri(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        F = (c - a) / (b - a);
        P = 1.0e-6 * (double)pRandom.Next(1000000);
        if (P > 0 && P < (F))
        {
            return a + Math.Sqrt(P * (b - a) * (c - a));
        }
        else
        {
            return b - Math.Sqrt((1 - P) * (b - a) * (b-c));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code and where you are stuck. We cannot answer this as long as there is no question.

Comment: You can look as 1 being the area of the triangle. You can think of the Probability Density function of the number of people in a store in a day.  a to b is time 9:00AM to 9:00PM and c being 5:00PM.  From 9 to 5 more people are entering the store than leaving like 4 enter each hour and 1 leaves store. From 5 to 9, 3 people leave each hour and 1 enter store.   If 100 people enter in one day, cumulative is the percentage of the people who have enter by time.  10:00AM 10% of the 100 have entered the store.  At 5:00PM 70% of 100 have entered the store.  9:00PM 100% of 100 have entered the store.

Comment: I'm not a C# programmer, but your code looks correct.  I think the problem is your grasp of what `a`, `b`, and `c` are.  `a` should be the lower bound for your range, `b` the upper bound, and `c` is the mode, i.e., the most likely outcome.  `c` **must** be a value between `a` and `b`, so values of 3, 8, and 14 are invalid choices.  That's why you never get to the `else` clause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You haven't said what you are trying to achieve.  From looking at that Wikipedia article, if you want to generate different values for x, it seems to me that you need to say something like,
`if (rand < f(a,b,c)) { x = a + Math.Sqrt(rand * (b-a) * (c-a)); } else { x = b - Math.Sqrt((1 - rand) * (b-a) * (b-c));}`

Comment: Thanks, What i'm trying to find out is exactly that f(a, b, c).

Comment: What error are you getting from your existing code?  I think how you define F will work.  The only problem I can see is, the second formula should start with `b -`.  Also, consider using `Random.NextDouble()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help IglooGreg. My problem is i never reach the "else" statement when i use arguments over 1 for the a, b, c variables.

Comment: I've had a breakthrough and now i understand the issue, sorry for the bother!

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The `if/else` is to evaluate the correct portion of the distribution based on whether the `x` comes from below the mode (c) or above it.  That's determined by what proportion of outcomes fall below the mode, which is calculated by evaluating the Cumulative Distribution Function, *not* the density, at the mode.

Comment: @pjs, can you give a better answer then?  I did not give a definition of f(a,b,c) so I don't know how you can say my definition  is wrong!

Comment: @pjs, Do you disagree with the Wikipedia article, or in my interpretation of it?  You say above that you are not a C# programmer.  As my answer is written in C#, is it possible that you might have misunderstood my answer?

Comment: @IglooGreg I'm a C/C++/ObjC/Java programmer, so I think I can read your answer, I just wouldn't try writing C# w/o a manual next to me.  Your answer's wrong because using the *correct* function f is an essential part of the algorithm.  Without a specification of the function and because this is a problem from probability, I evaluated it in probability terms, where little-f is the generic description of a density function and is **not** the right thing to use.  Better answer - OP's post-edit code looks correct, I suspect s/he transposed the use of `b` and `c`.

Comment: @pjs, I didn't give a complete solution because I understood the idea on SO was to guide the OP towards the answer rather than to give them the complete solution. At the time, they hadn't listed their code so I was trying to check that I had understood their problem before I went too far. The fact that they have now edited their code to look like mine suggests that I was along the right lines. I would have been happy to give more help including the definition of the f() function if needed.  Sorry for calling it f(), this was a stupid name to give it!

Comment: And you may be incorrect that the OP has got b and c the wrong way round. They say, "the minimum, mode and maximum will be something like 3, 8 and 14", so I think they would have assigned appropriate values to a , b and c. Their code certainly looks correct.

Comment: @IglooGreg Given that the correct order of arguments is minimum, maximum, and mode, *not* "minimum, mode and maximum", I think that OP has correct code but is not running it correctly.  That would explain why s/he says above that the `else` is never reached -- `(c-a) / (b-a)` is the proportion of outcomes the `if` should be evaluated, and **must** be a number less than or equal to 1.  It will always come out > 1, and hence the `else` will never be reached, if `b` and `c` are interchanged.

Comment: Given that the OP has moved on, I intend to do the same now.